# Python imitate class's constructor only using function dynamically

Tags: python

This is a little bit weird. I want to dynamic initialize part of function's parameters before I call it. But I don't want to use class for some reason. Let's say I have a function:

```
def inner(a,b,c):
"a,b,c do something"
return result
```

Before I formally call it, I'd like to initialize it somewhere:

```
partInitalAbc=inner(,b,c)
```

Then I'll use it as:

```
result=partInitialAbc(a)
```

Please notice I want to do this dynamically. Just as when you initial a class using the constructor, so a decorator may be not appropriate at this time...

Any one have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

> Return a new `partial` object which when called will behave like *func* called with the positional arguments *args* and keyword arguments *keywords*.

If you pass the arguments to `partial` as positional arguments, they'll appear at the beginning of the argument list, which isn't exactly what you want. Keyword arguments give you more control over which parameters are passed:

```
partInitialAbc = functools.partial(inner, b=b_value, c=c_value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ^_^. I came up with a idea that if I wrap this in a function. Then I can only expose b c to users. Actually I can customize any parameters exposed to users then. And that will be what I want. Hoping it's not too redundant though...